# How to sort an ArrayList using two sorts

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a list of names that have the gender and a count of how many people have that name.

Ex:

John M 600

Mike M 200

Sarah F 700

Tom M 400

Emily F 600

Chris M 600

I am trying to sort the names in descending order by the count and if they have the same count i want them to be sorted in ABC order. Function I made separately prints the count in ABC order and than prints another that is in descending order .

**example: What is happening**

Chris M 600

Emily F 600

Mike M 200

John M 600

Sarah F 700

Tom M 400

Sarah F 700

John M 600

Emily F 600

Chris M 600

Tom M 400

Mike M 200

**What I am trying to get**

Sarah F 700

Chris M 600

Emily F 600

John M 600

Tom M 400

Mike M 200

```
ArrayList<OneName> oneName = new ArrayList<OneName>();
while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {

    // read a line from the input file via sc into line
        line = sc.nextLine();



        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        String name = stk.nextToken();
        char sex = stk.nextToken().charAt(0);
        int count = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());


        OneName list = new OneName(name, sex, count);

        oneName.add(list);      



    }    Collections.sort(oneName, new OneNameCompare());

    for(OneName a: oneName)
    {
        System.out.println(a.toString());

    }
     Collections.sort(oneName, new OneNameCountCompare());
     for(OneName b: oneName)
    {

        System.out.println(b.toString());


     }
```

**OneNameCompare.java**

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;
public class OneNameCompare implements Comparator<OneName>
{

    public int compare(OneName a1, OneName a2)
    {
         return a1.getName().compareTo(a2.getName());
    }


 }
```

**OneNameCountCompare.java**

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;

public class OneNameCountCompare implements Comparator<OneName>
{
    {
     if(b1.getCount() < b2.getCount())
     {
        return 1;
     }
 else
 {
    return -1; 
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Why not combine both checks into a single comparator?

Comment: For my project they have to be in two separate ones.

Comment: What you try to get, shouldn't "Chris M 600" come after "Emily F 600" and after "John M 600"?

Comment: Your `OneNameCountCompare` is incomplete. What you have posted won’t compile and can’t have produced the output.

Comment: it compiles and works for me

Answer (score 2):

### Java 8 solution

You can combine both comparators via [`thenComparing(Comparator<? super T> other)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) method introduced to Comparator in Java 8.

So instead of

```
Collections.sort(oneName, new OneNameCompare());
for (OneName a : oneName) {
    System.out.println(a.toString());

}

Collections.sort(oneName, new OneNameCountCompare());
for (OneName b : oneName) {
    System.out.println(b.toString());
}
```

use

```
Collections.sort(oneName, new OneNameCountCompare()
                              .thenComparing(new OneNameCompare()));
for (OneName b : oneName) {
    System.out.println(b.toString());
}
```

BTW it seems that you can "simplify" your code a little using new Java 8 features called [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to simply create required Comparators.

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

//...

Comparator<OneName> reversedCountComparator = comparing(OneName::getCount).reversed();
Comparator<OneName> nameComparator = comparing(OneName::getName);

oneName.sort(reversedCountComparator.thenComparing(nameComparator));

oneName.forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

### Java 7 solution.

Since `Collections.sort(collection, comparator)` accept only one comparator you need to create class which will implement Comparator, but will internally use your other comparators. Code of such class can look like

```
class ComparatorsMixer<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    List<Comparator<T>> comparatorsList;

    public ComparatorsMixer(List<Comparator<T>> list) {
        this.comparatorsList = list;
    }

    public ComparatorsMixer() {
        comparatorsList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addComparator(Comparator<T> comparator){
        comparatorsList.add(comparator);
    }
    
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        for (Comparator<T> c : comparatorsList) {
            int result = c.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0)
                return result;
            //if result == 0 then move on to next comparator
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and you can use it like

```
ComparatorsMixer<OneName> mix = new ComparatorsMixer<>();
mix.addComparator(new OneNameCountCompare());
mix.addComparator(new OneNameCompare());

Collections.sort(oneName, mix);
```

Comment: I am getting a cannot find symbol error:                              .thenComparing(new OneNameCountCompare()));

Comment: @Tro Are you using Java8?

Comment: I am using java version "1.7.0_65"

Comment: @Tro So you are using Java 7. Consider updating your Java to 8, so you could be able to use many awesome features like default methods (`thenComparing` is one of them). To be able to use them in your IDEs you will have to use their newest versions like Eclipse 4.4 (Lina), NetBeans8, IntelliJ IDEA 13.

Comment: It is a class project so it has to run on 7. Is there a possibility that you would know an alternative for 7?

Answer (score 1):

Just print the result after the second compare. Collections.sort uses a 'stable sort' algorithm, which means that for equal items in the second sort, the order remains the same as after the first sort, which is exactly what you want, no?

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Of course, a better solution is to combine the comparators, so you need only one pass over the items.