# Sort collection with multiple criteria

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Assume I have a list ["d", "a", "y / a", "a / z", "b / a / c", "a / c / a"]
I need to sort it with the next way:

1. it should be sorted by the number of slashes
2. afterward it should be sorted by alphabet
   Result:
   [**"a"**, **"d"**, **"a / z"**, **"y / a"**, **"a / c / a"**, **"b / a / c"**]

the first part is working with this:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(s -> StringUtils.countMatches(s, "/"));
map.keySet().stream().sorted(comparator).forEach(System.out::println);
```

but the **result**:
[**"d"**, **"a"**, **"y / a"**, **"a / z"**, **"b / a / c"**, **"a / c / a"**]

Comment: `StringUtils.countMatches(s, "//")` should probably be `StringUtils.countMatches(s, "/")`

Comment: yup why are you using 2 slashes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an ArrayList using two sorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149732/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-using-two-sorts)

Comment: and `comparing(` could probably be `comparingInt(`

Comment: `StringUtils.countMatches(s, "/")` may be `s.split("/").length`.

Comment: @saka1029 bad idea, it will create a new array. bad for performance.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are disregarding the "*afterward it should be sorted by alphabet*" part. This is easily fixable, because `Comparator`s are composable. Just add `.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, which will resolve the incorrect ordering of equivalent (in terms of `/` count) elements by ordering them in the default (natural) way, i.e. alphabetically, when speaking about `String`s:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(
        s -> StringUtils.countMatches(s, "//")
).thenComparing(
        Comparator.naturalOrder()
));
```

In addition, you probably meant `"/"` rather than `"//"`.

Comment: I do not know `StringUtils`, but does `countMatches` not return an `int`?

Comment: it is not working *Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> StringUtils.countMatches(s, "/")).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());* 
try to put it in the code

Comment: @java-dev-ua What's not working for you? I don't have direct access to `StringUtils`, but [this code](https://pastebin.com/RzVvUcfE)'s output is **exactly** the same as yours. Maybe you forgout about the last `)`? Or you (likely) forgot to change `comparingInt` to `comparing`?

Comment: Working example on [ideone](https://ideone.com/Wdr2xQ) (just had to add type to `s` to avoid casting or a second assignment)

Comment: @user15244370 it is JS, not Java. check my solution. It is a bit different.

Comment: @java-dev-ua what is JS? JavaScript? the ideone code I posted is Java and not Javascript (on right side of code field you can see the language -> "language: Java (HotSpot 12)")

Comment: @user15244370 output result is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is:

```
Collections.sort(listStrings, ((Comparator<String>)(o1, o2) -> {
            int i = o1.split("/").length - o2.split("/").length;
            if (i == 0) return o1.compareTo(o2);
            return i;
        }).thenComparing(String::compareTo));
```

OR

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt((String o) -> StringUtils.countMatches(o, "/"))
        .thenComparing(String::compareTo)
);
```

Comment: well "correct"? The first solution not so much (IMHO). 1) I thought you wanted to have it sorted by count of `/` - but that is ignoring slashes on end of text (e.g. `" a / b ////"` will be sorted before `"a / b / c"`) it is missing the second argument of `split` 2) why `thenComparing`? It is already doing the `comperaTo` inside of first comparator ( 3) it is changing the original list, streams solutions do not change the original list)